# Excel Not Downloading

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I want to fill data in excel and download that excel..
Following is the code..

```
 public void DownloadExcel(int acid, int GroupId)
    {
        // Working Code
        #region DownloadExcel
        // string sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrainingMVCContext"].ConnectionString;
        string sConnectionString = string.Empty;
        LoginUserDetails objLoginUserDetails = (LoginUserDetails)InsiderTrading.Common.Common.GetSessionValue((string)ConstEnum.SessionValue.UserDetails);
        sConnectionString = objLoginUserDetails.CompanyDBConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("st_tra_NSEDownloadGroupWiseExcel", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupId", GroupId);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        //  ds = new DataSet(); 

        adp.Fill(dt);


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook mWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets mWorkSheets;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet mWSheet1;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        string directory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Document"];

        string path = "Z:\\For Excel Demo\\Application\\InsiderTrading\\Document" + "\\" + "Stock Exchange Submission.xlsx";
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;
        oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
        mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;
        mWSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = mWSheet1.UsedRange;

        for (var row = 4; row <= dt.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            for (var col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                mWSheet1.Cells[row + 1, col + 1].Value = dt.Rows[row - 1][col];
            }
        }

        string Filename = "Testing.xlsx";
        string pathTosave = (Path.Combine(directory, Filename));
        mWorkBook.SaveAs(pathTosave);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Response.Charset = "";
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + pathTosave);
            System.Text.StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            //strHTMLContent.Append(LetterHTMLContent);
            HttpContext.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
            HttpContext.Response.End();
            HttpContext.Response.Flush();


        }
        mWorkBook.Close();
        mWSheet1 = null;
        mWorkBook = null;
        oXL.Quit();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();





        #endregion DownloadExcel
    }
```

but it gives the error For line

```
 mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

error msg as follows--

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in InsiderTrading.dll but was not handled in user code

How can i do that..Plz help

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a library, "LinqToExcell" to do all the plumbing?

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659643/Csharp-Query-Excel-and-CSV-Files-Using-LinqToExcel

Just upload the file using the following code in your controller. Note, you will need to save the file in your application because browsers do not allow you to access the location of your uploaded file (security purposes):

```
    #region ImportExcell

    public ActionResult ImportExcel()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ImportExcel(HttpPostedFileBase upload, FormCollection fc)
    {
        var v = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["upload"];
        string contentType = upload.ContentType;

        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(upload.FileName);

        //I am only allowing this kind of excel file. I got this from HttpPostedFileBase during debuging and checking content
        if (!contentType.Contains(@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("This is not a valid file. This is '{0}'", contentType));
            return View();
        }

        var fileName = upload.FileName;

        //This is my temporary saving spot in my application
        var filePathSaveTo = Server.MapPath(@"/Upload/ExcelFile");
        string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePathSaveTo, fileName);

        //Now we need to save the file in a temp spot so we can access it later
        upload.SaveAs(savedFileName);

        try
        {
            string returnMsg = _fileDocDAL.LoadFromExcel(savedFileName);
            ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Done! " + returnMsg));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = AliKuli.Utilities.ExceptionNS.ErrorMsgClass.GetInnerException(e);
            ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format(error));

        } 

        return View();


    }

    #endregion
```

And your view....

```
@model ModelsClassLibrary.Models.Documents.FilesNS.FilesDocImportVM


@using (Html.BeginForm("ImportExcel", "FileDocs", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Required Fields
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Excel File", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="upload" id="front"  />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" /> |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My model is as below, but you need to make your model just like the data in the excel sheet. This is all explained in the documentation for LinqToExcell

```
namespace ModelsClassLibrary.Models.Documents.FilesNS
{
    //[NotMapped]
    public class FilesDocImportVM
    {
        public FilesDocImportVM()
        {
           FileId = -1;
        }
#region Files
    /// <summary>
    /// The file number's ID
    /// </summary>
    public int FileId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the file number that the user sees.
    /// </summary>
    public string FileNo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the name of the file
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// This is the parent's ID. 0 means no ID
    /// </summary>
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

#endregion

    public int GetFileNumberFromOldFileNumber()
    {
        if (FileNo.IsNullOrEmpty() || FileId == -1 || Description.IsNullOrEmpty())
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Proper Data not received. Record is {0}.FilesDocImportVM.GetFileNumberFromOldFileNumber ", this.ToString()));


        return new FileDoc().GetFileNumberFromOldFileNumber(FileNo);
    }

    public void SelfErrorCheck()
    {
        if(FileId == -1 || FileNo.IsNullOrEmpty() || Description.IsNullOrEmpty())
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Proper Data not received. Record is {0}. FilesDocImportVM.SelfErrorCheck", this.ToString()));

    }
#region Category
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the categories ID
    /// </summary>
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// This is the name of the category
    /// </summary>
    public string CategoryName { get; set; } 
#endregion

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("FileId: {0}, FileNo: {1}, Description: {2}, ParentId: {3}, CategoryId: {4}, CategoryName: {5}",
            FileId,
            FileNo,
            Description,
            ParentId,
            CategoryId,
            CategoryName);
     }

    }
}
```

The uploading code is pretty simple... this is the code that is used

```
    public string LoadFromExcel(string excelFileName)
    {
        int noOfFiles = 0;
//*** NOTE - The line below is the code to import from Excel. I have wrapped it a bit to make it simple... the wrapper is below. The code after this line is just for fixing and checking the data.
        var excelFile = AliKuli.Utilities.ExcellUtility.ImportFromExcelWithHeader(excelFileName, "AliKuliFiles");
        if (excelFile.IsNullOrEmpty())
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Utility Class failed to load. FileDocsDAL.LoadFromExcel"));

        string totalFilesMsg = string.Format("Total Orignal Files: {0}", excelFile.Count());

        var dataArray = excelFile.OrderBy(x => x.FileId).ToList();

        if (dataArray.IsNullOrEmpty())
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Data array failed to load. FileDocsDAL.LoadFromExcel"));

        CheckTheData(dataArray);

        //first make the categories
        User theUser = Get_User();

        string temp = "";
        if (noOfFiles == 324)
            temp = "Found";

        CreateCategories(dataArray, theUser);
        CreateAndSaveFile(ref noOfFiles, dataArray, theUser);

        //now add the parents
        SaveTheParents();

        totalFilesMsg += " Counted: " + noOfFiles;
        //CreateFileWithCategory(dataArray, admin);
        return totalFilesMsg;
    }
```

This is the wrapper code I wrote to wrap the LinqToExcel

```
public static class ExcellUtility
{

    /// <summary>
    /// This will read in the excel file such that it will stringify the cols of each row. 
    /// Example. If there are 3 cols, the the first 3 entries will be for col 0, then 1, then Col 2,
    /// then... the 4th entry will again be col1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<FilesDocImportVM> ImportFromExcelWithHeader(string excelFileName, string sheetName)
    {

        ExcelUtilityClass euc;
        ExcelQueryFactory excel;
        MakeExcelUtilityClass(excelFileName, out euc, out excel);

        //This creates a IQueriable<FilesDocImportVM>
        var data = from c in excel.Worksheet<FilesDocImportVM>(sheetName) select c;
        var colNames = excel.GetColumnNames(sheetName).ToArray();

        var datalist = data.ToList();

        return datalist;

    }

    private static void MakeExcelUtilityClass(string excelFileName, out ExcelUtilityClass euc, out ExcelQueryFactory excel)
    {
        if (excelFileName.IsNullOrEmpty())
            throw new Exception("No Excel File Name Passed");

        euc = new ExcelUtilityClass();
        excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelFileName);
    }
  }
}
```

Looks more complicated than it is... the uploading part was easy - just about one line of code after writing a the wrapper.

Good luck.